# Map list to list of lists by index (Python)

Tags: python, list, mapping, binning

I'm looking for an efficient way to map a list of values, say

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

to another list, containing lists of values of the same total range, for example

```
z = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]].
```

What I need to know is basically the index a value from x corresponds to in z. `x[0]=1` would correspond to `z[0]`, because it falls in the first bin of z, where `x[7]=8` would correspond to `z[2]`, because it falls in the third bin.

How do I identify that index of the sublists of z for each x value? In my case, x has about 50,000 values, z has about 5,000 sublists, and I have lots of those lists, so I'm looking for a way to do that as fast as possible.

Comment: If you want an efficient solution, you're going to tell us more about your data. Are there always numbers? If yes, in what range? Are the lists sorted etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dict here:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> z = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> dic = {y :i for i,a in enumerate(z) for y in a}
>>> dic[7]
2
>>> dic[8]
2
>>> dic[1]
0
```

Comment: For Python versions < 2.7: `dic = dict((y, i) for i,x in enumerate(z) for y in x)`

Comment: This doesn't work for arbitrary float values. dic[7.3] raises an error. How can I correct that? using float(y) when constructing the dict made no difference.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary When I enter dic[7], I get 2. When I enter dic[7.3], then I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 7.2999999999999998`

Comment: @frixhax Use `str(y)` then, because floats have precision issues : `1.1 + .1` returns `1.2000000000000002`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Where do you mean I should use str? Can you test it in the above example? I tried it as described above by yourself with `dic = dict((y, i) for i,x in enumerate(z) for y in x)`, because I am running Python 2.6. Can you get that code to return "2" when looking for the value 7.3?

Comment: @frixhax what would be your expected value for 6.4?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That is a good question. In this case I'd say the edges of bins 1 and 2 are 6 and 7, so the border would be 6.5. Hence the 6.4 would return 1.

Comment: @frixhax try `round()`, `dic[round(7.3)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> y = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> map(lambda x: [i for i in range(len(y)) if y[i].count(x) > 0], x)
[[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [2], [2], [2]]
>>> 
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> y = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [1,2,3]]
>>> map(lambda x: [i for i in range(len(y)) if y[i].count(x) > 0], x)
[[0, 3], [0, 3], [0, 3], [1], [1], [1], [2], [2], [2]]
>>> 
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> y = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 9, 7]]
>>> map(lambda x: [i for i in range(len(y)) if y[i].count(x) > 0], x)
[[0, 3], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [2, 3], [2], [2, 3]]
>>> 
>>> x = [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [1, 9, 7], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> map(lambda x: [i for i in range(len(y)) if y[i].count(x) > 0], x)
[[3], [3], [3], [1, 2], [1], [1, 2], [0, 2], [0], [0]]
>>> 

>>> x = [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [1, 9, 7], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(map(lambda x: (x, [i for i in range(len(y)) if y[i].count(x) > 0]), x))
>>> d
{1: [0, 2], 2: [0], 3: [0], 4: [3], 5: [3], 6: [3], 7: [1, 2], 8: [1], 9: [1, 2]}
>>>
```

I think it works!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are searching in intervals and you could use an Interval Tree. A quick google shows https://github.com/tylerkahn/intervaltree-python, and with some modification, I expect it to work quite efficiently.

My modified module is found at http://pastebin.com/M6rpYt44 and simply adds a sequential attribute, `key`, if it does not already exist.

```
from IntervalTree import *

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
z = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

intervals = [Interval(l[0],l[-1]) for l in z]
it = IntervalTree(intervals)

# search
[it.search(i)[0].key for i in x]
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```